# Refresh a generated image

Tags: javascript, html, image, refresh, src

I am fairly unfamiliar with web technology.

A software that embeds a web server output a dynamic image
on the local host:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/" alt="http://localhost:8000/" class="transparent shrinkToFit" width="419" height="428">
```

This image is updated regularly by the software. I am trying to display this update in the web browser. There are several related posts and I have tried two solutions but so far with no luck.

Below are two attempts inspired by existing code and both fail. The problem seems to be related to some caching effect but I am not sure how to work around this.

Thanks in advance,

Trad

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="rsc/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<!--        <script>
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var url = "http://localhost:8000";//document.getElementById("url").value;
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("GET",url);
                        xhr.responseType = "blob";
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE && xhr.status == 200 ) { // xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE &&
                            // Render the downloaded image
                            var myblob = xhr.response;
                            var image = document.getElementById("ImageMusic");

                            image.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(evt.target.src);
                            });
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.send(null);
                    }, 100);



        </script>
-->
                <script>
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var myImageElement = document.getElementById('ImageMusic');
                        myImageElement.src = 'http://localhost:8000?rand=' + Math.random();
                    }, 100);
                </script>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

        <a-scene>
            <a-assets>
                <img id="ImageMusic" src="http://localhost:8000" />
            </a-assets>
            <a-image position="1 1 -4" width="4" height="4" src="#ImageMusic"></a-image>
        </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope setting image *src* again may force it to reload like *iframe* does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use a web page as an image or texture.

In the context of A-Frame, you cannot use I-Frames as an image or texture either, it is not possible in the browser.

Comment: Are you saying this method does not work or that what I am trying to achieve is not feasible (or at least not in a straight forward way) ? I did some further experimenation today and the commented code where the setInterval is actually works on a normal image. I undestand better what it does now and I tried to use it directly on the A-image. Since it does just update the src, I was thinking it could very well work on a generic object and also in the particular case of a a-image. It did not. Not familiar enough with web development to decide whether that is expected or not.

Comment: More interestingly, do you know of a way to refresh the image in a-frame ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using iframe
 `<iframe src="http://localhost:8000/">Your browser does not support the iframe HTML tag</iframe>` 
This should update automatically.

Alternatively, you can use the `<embed src="http://localhost:8000/"></embed>` tag. As long as you have a set pixel size for the images, (eg: 1080x720), you shouldn't have any problems with scrolling or stretched images.

CSS:

`embed {
    width:1080px;
    height: 720px;
}`

Comment: It seems these two elements are meant to be displayed. I am looking for a solution that refreshes the reference as the display happens through another object <a-image> from the A-frame library. Thanks for the answer anyway.